# MotionEvent.obtain() Multitouch Event for API < 9

Tags: android, testing, multi-touch

I'm trying to simulate multitouch events using [MotionEvent.obtain()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain%28long,%20long,%20int,%20int,%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerProperties%5B%5D,%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerCoords%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). This can be done using methods introduced in API9 and API14:

```
API 9:
public static MotionEvent obtain (long downTime, long eventTime, int action, int pointerCount, int[] pointerIds, PointerCoords[] pointerCoords, int metaState, float xPrecision, float yPrecision, int deviceId, int edgeFlags, int source, int flags)
API 14:
public static MotionEvent obtain (long downTime, long eventTime, int action, int pointerCount, PointerProperties[] pointerProperties, PointerCoords[] pointerCoords, int metaState, int buttonState, float xPrecision, float yPrecision, int deviceId, int edgeFlags, int source, int flags)
```

However, my application needs to support API >= 7. The latest method below that API is

```
API 5:
public static MotionEvent obtain (long downTime, long eventTime, int action, int pointerCount, float x, float y, float pressure, float size, int metaState, float xPrecision, float yPrecision, int deviceId, int edgeFlags)
```

It does accept ***pointerCount***, but only accepts coordinates for one of the pointers. So I'm not sure how to use this method to simulate multitouch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check what version is being used, and call the appropriate version.  Of course you can also just use the oldest version, deprecated doesn't mean it won't work-  it means they want to wean people off of it and may remove it in the distant future, but are currently keeping it in for backwards compatibility.  It can still be used.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: it is impossible to generate MotionEvents representing multitouch events (i.e. containing information about multiple pointers) using MotionEvent.obtain() from API < 9.

Therefore I simply skipped devices of API < 9 in my multitouch tests by using @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)